# In which scenarios method level security helps than url level security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am making a simple web application using Spring MVC and Spring Security. Can somebody explain me in which scenarios we need method level security and the URL level security? 
Because we can restrict an user of a particular role from accessing a page through URL level security or by keeping security tags in the view for an action. So, how could the user access a method from service layer? In such scenarios how could the method level security helps? Please explain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method level security can be considered as addition to URL level security. For example we may want some URLs within our application to be secured, requiring the role ROLE_USER to access them. This can be achieved by means of URL level security.

```
https://domain.com/entities/5
```

Consider URL above that can be secured with URL level security as follows.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/entities/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

However, at times you need more fine-grained security. For example you may want to allow to access the given entity (id=5) only to their owners. This is something you are not able to achieve by URL level security but can be accomplished by means of method level security.

Comment: So, we can access method argument as an annotation parameters for securing in more deeper. Good answer. Thanks for clarifying.